# Access #ident information in an executable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

gcc (and other compilers) [support](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Other-Directives.html#Other-Directives) the #ident preprocessor directive:

> The ‘#ident’ directive takes one argument, a string constant. On some
>   systems, that string constant is copied into a special segment of the
>   object file. On other systems, the directive is ignored. The ‘#sccs’
>   directive is a synonym for ‘#ident’.

And I see (with a hex dump) that by e.g. adding this to a source file:

```
#ident "Hello there !"
```

This string gets embedded in the executable.

Now, are there any tools (readelf,objdump, gdb or others) that can extract/view these strings ?

Comment: Classically (on SVR4 and similar versions of Unix), there was a program `mcs` (manipulate comment section) and the `#ident` information went into the comment section.  You could arrange to compress the comment section (removing duplicate entries) and delete it and list it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have RCS installed, I think the `ident` command will display them. This assumes you format them in the conventional way: `$keyword: value $`.

Without this keyword, the traditional way to get ident strings into binaries is by putting them in static variables, e.g.

```
static char const rcsid[] =
"$Id: f.c,v 5.4 1993/11/09 17:40:15 eggert Exp $";
```

The problem with this is that you get warnings about unused variables, and compilers might optimize them away. So you have to put bogus uses of the variables in your code to prevent this. Also, if ident strings are put in header files, they have to follow naming conventions to avoid conflicts.

I can't find a specification for where `#ident` puts them. I suspect they're just stuck somewhere in the pure data section, so that they can be found just like the above string.

Comment: The `#ident` directive is wholly separate from RCS keywords.  It is a C preprocessor directive.  Things like header files would contain a `#ident` that would identify the file included in the compilation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But the only purpose of it is to get those strings into the binary, so that commands like `ident` can find them. It's basically a replacement for the hack of putting them in external variables.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, albeit it's a bit picky, the string format must be $keyword: value $  (a space before the last $)

Answer (score 0):

`strings -a` will find it -- along with a lot of other stuff.  (Experiment shows that `strings` without `-a` doesn't find it; apparently it's not stored in the data section.)

As the name `#sccs` implies, it was originally intended for use with the old SCCS version control system, which can expand keywords in files as they're checked out. You can do something similar with the slightly more modern RCS and CVS systems, which have a different keyword syntax.  I don't remember the details of SCCS, but for RCS or CVS you can have something like:

```
#ident "$Header:$"
```

which will be expanded on RCS or CVS checkout to, for example,

```
#ident $Header: /path/to/foo.txt,v 1.6 2013/04/02 20:21:33 yourname Exp $
```

You can then use the `ident` command to find strings like that, even in binaries.  (`ident` is part of RCS, not CVS.)

Even if you're not using RCS or CVS, you can still use the same keyword syntax:

```
#ident "$Header: anything you like here$"
```

(But your text can be clobbered if you check the file into an RCS or CVS repository.)

Comment: That finds the string, though I was looking for something that would just fish out the #ident words - with strings/strings -a you'd have to know the string beforehand or atleast prefix it with something known to grep for it.